# Object loading with binary loader in three.js is not working

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I am trying to modify the code of three.js example to load the .obj which is converted in .js. That uses BinaryLoader.js to load the object. the object is not displaying in my modified code. My code so far is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                background:#000;
                color:#fff;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                font-family:georgia;
                text-align:center;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/loaders/BinaryLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var CARS = {

                "Porsche":  {

                    name:   "Bugatti Veyron",
                    url:    "obj/car/Porsche_911_GT2.js",
                //  author: '<a href="http://artist-3d.com/free_3d_models/dnm/model_disp.php?uid=1129" target="_blank">Troyano</a>',
                    init_rotation: [ 0, 0, 0 ],
                    scale: 5.5,
                    //init_material: 4,
                    //body_materials: [ 2 ],

                    object: null,
                    buttons: null,
                    materials: null

                }


            };

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );


            var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader( true );
            document.body.appendChild( loader.statusDomElement );
                // CAMERAS

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000 );

                // SCENE

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                    // LIGHTS

                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x050505 );
                scene.add( ambient );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.setFaceCulling( THREE.CullFaceNone );
                renderer.autoClear = false;

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                loader.load( CARS[ "Porsche" ].url, function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, "Porsche" ) } );

            }

            function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            render();

            }

            function render() {

                var timer = -0.0002 * Date.now();

                camera.position.x = 1000 * Math.cos( timer );
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
                camera.position.z = 1000 * Math.sin( timer );

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                    renderer.render( scene, camera );


            }



    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone know this problem?

Comment: can you please provide a link to download your object's .js file ?

Comment: sorry, can you please tell me where should I attach the object's .js file?

Comment: hey this is link for my object's .js file https://www.dropbox.com/s/kt4ehcvwuh9gecq/Porsche_911_GT2.js?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a JSON model so you need a JSONLoader instead of a BinaryLoader, another problem is that your model is small, so you have to scale it by 200 in order to be viewable from your initialized camera(with fov=70). I will go with the following code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(true);

loader.load(CARS[ "Porsche" ].url, function (geometry)
{
    /*createScene( geometry, "Porsche" )*/
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.scale.set(200,200,200);
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

**UPDATE:** Full code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            background: #000;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: georgia;
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/loaders/BinaryLoader.js"></script>

<script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

<script>

    if (!Detector.webgl) {
        Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
    }
    var mouseY = 0;
    var CARS = {

        "Porsche": {

            name: "Bugatti Veyron",
            url: "obj/car/Porsche_911_GT2.js",
            //  author: '<a href="http://artist-3d.com/free_3d_models/dnm/model_disp.php?uid=1129" target="_blank">Troyano</a>',
            init_rotation: [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            scale: 5.5,
            //init_material: 4,
            //body_materials: [ 2 ],

            object: null,
            buttons: null,
            materials: null

        }


    };

    var container, stats;

    var camera, scene, renderer;

    init();
    animate();

    function init()
    {

        container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);

        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(true);
        document.body.appendChild(loader.statusDomElement);
        // CAMERAS

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000);

        // SCENE

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // LIGHTS

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x050505);
        scene.add(ambient);

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setFaceCulling(THREE.CullFaceNone);
        renderer.autoClear = false;

        loader.load(CARS[ "Porsche" ].url, function (geometry)
        {
            /*createScene( geometry, "Porsche" )*/
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            mesh.scale.set(200,200,200);
            scene.add(mesh);
        });

        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    }

    function animate()
    {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        render();

    }

    function render()
    {

        var timer = -0.0002 * Date.now();

        camera.position.x = 1000 * Math.cos(timer);
        camera.position.y += ( -mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
        camera.position.z = 1000 * Math.sin(timer);

        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Michel Kogan, thanks for your answer. I had modified the changes which you have suggested. But still black screen coming and object is not displaying. Is there any requirement of some other files with my object's .js file which I may be missing, that's why object is not displaying?

Comment: @kiran I updated my answer with the tested full code, in case you have problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michel Kogan for your help. Its working fine now.